# Regular expression to match a missing number in a string sequence

Tags: c++, regex, string, parsing

I'm reproducing verbatim a coding exercise statement below:

- Given a string consisting only of digits representing a sequence, the goal is to find a missing number. For instance, given the string `596597598600601602` the missing number is `599`. You may assume all the numbers
  are positive integers and the sequence increases by one at
  each number except the missing number. The numbers 
  will have no more than `six digits` and the string will have
  no more than four hundred characters.

I've managed to come up with the solution in C++ code without using any regular expression whatsoever. Will the incorporation of regular expressions in the logic either simplify the logic or reduce the complexity? If yes, some pointers on how I can go about the task would be appreciated.

Comment: `If yes, some pointers `.............No...............

Comment: Regex and math don't mix, so no.

Comment: I've removed the C# tag since I can't see anything relating to C# here. Regex is completely the wrong thing to use here though.

Comment: Just as a sidenote... I hope you are handling the 911 case... (from one digit to two digits)... unless you put as a precondition that the format is 0911...

Comment: @xanatos yes, handling digital length transition would be preferable in the eventual solution, if not for the first cut.

Comment: @lifebalance (spoiler) considering you seems to be at the first cut, here there is a possible second cut :-) <spoiler> https://ideone.com/ubWnZD </spoler>